# WPF window that looks like excel

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

I am new to WPF and c#, and I am trying trying to create an excel like table with a fixed number of columns and a varying number of rows according to the user's needs.People advise to use a datagrid, but I am very confused, some say that it is used mostly to display data source content (which is data contained in database if I understood). I read also about listviews, binding things to itemsource...etc. This is really a lot of information to work with! What I simply need is a way to create a table with fixed columns, and adding rows automatically when the user clicks on a button, that's it! No binding, or anything of this sort.But how to achieve that? Also, if you have good websites tutorials for working with datagrids, I would be very grateful (most of those that I found are too much complex, or don't explain well).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unlikely you can work on a WPF project without using `Binding` and my opinion is that you will have to use a `DataGrid`

Comment: WPF, DataBinding, and MVVM all go hand-in-hand. I suggest you start looking for tutorials on those items, before going further.

Comment: I recently wrote something on my blog [explaining WPF's DataContext](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). It may help you understand WPF and its binding system a bit better. Basically WPF has two layers: the UI layer and the data layer. The data layer (`DataContext`) is your actual application and is entirely in code, while your UI layer just sits on top of the data layer and provides a user-friendly interface for the user to interact with the data layer. Bindings simply provide a way for the UI layer to lookup values in the data layer.

Comment: Thank you for the website Rachel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create datatemplates that will style your data to look however you like - in this case an Excel row.  Then you can display this data as the ItemsSource in an items control.  Since you want the number of rows to vary based on some criteria, your data should be in an ObservableCollection.  I'm not sure how you'd set-up the header, but I think you could style-up some containers and bind their width properties to the datatemplate controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do more cell level customizations, then you can try Grid
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/grid/grid-control